# How do you define & call a "variable.my_function" method in Ruby within a class?

Tags: ruby, class, methods

So the basic setting is the following:

in app/services/SomeService/ABC.rb

```
class SomeService::ABC 
 FORBIDDEN_CHARS = {" " => "+", "'" => "%27", "/" => "%2F", ":" => "%3A", "&" => "%26"}
 def my_function(input)
  #now do something fancy with the input
  var = .... #a String is created
  var.to_linkable
 # continue with something fancy
 end

 def to_linkable
  FORBIDDEN_CHARS.each{|key,value| self.gsub!(key,value)}
 end
end
```

This results in the error: **undefined method `to_linkable' for "bla bla":String**

However in this way it works:

```
def to_linkable(link)
    FORBIDDEN_CHARS.each{|key,value| link.gsub!(key,value)}
end
```

but I have to call it with 'to_linkable(link)' instead of just putting 'link.to_linkable'. If I copy paste my code in the Terminal the first way, there is no errors when calling 'link.to_linkable'.

So my question is: How (and where?) do I properly create such a to_linkable method? I might want to use it later on so that's why I want it to be an easy to use method. Thanks very much :)
And yes, I am a Ruby newbie, coming over from Matlab :D

Comment: monkey patching

Comment: Wow, thanks for such quick and helpful responses! Extending the String Class worked (URI replaces the chars differently than me) and I understood some more bites :-)

Comment: Yes, the behaviour of `Uri.escape` is slightly different to yours. But does it matter? Unless you have a good reason not to use it (which could of course just be for fun/as a learning exercise!), always go with the "standard" solution :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, don't reinvent the wheel. Use [`URI.escape`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI/Escape.html), instead of trying to manually define which characters to replace.

However, for the sake of learning, if we go with your implementation...

`var` is a string. If you wish to call a method **on the string**, then it must be defined in the `String` class. It is usually not advised to add methods to core classes like this, but the following would work:

```
class String
  FORBIDDEN_LINK_CHARS = {" " => "+", ...}
  def to_linkable
    FORBIDDEN_LINK_CHARS.each{|key,value| self.gsub!(key,value)}
    self
  end
end

"hello world".to_linkable # => "hello+world"
```

Alternatively, if you don't want to extend the `String` class, but still wish to call an instance method without passing the variable, then you need to somewhere set `var` as an **instance variable** in the class. This may or may not be a good idea, depending on the structure of the class.

For example, the following works:

```
class SomeService::ABC 
  FORBIDDEN_CHARS = {" " => "+", ...}
  def my_function(input)
    @var = .... #a String is created
    make_var_linkable
  end

  def make_var_linkable
    FORBIDDEN_CHARS.each{|key,value| @var.gsub!(key,value)}
  end
end
```

...However, going back to my original point, the **actual** implementation I'd recommend is neither of the above. Just do:

```
require 'uri'

class SomeService::ABC 
  def my_function(input)
    var = URI.escape(....)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Both answers given so far are using `FORBIDDEN_LINK_CHARS.length` number of `gsub` operations, which is not quite optimal.

```
module StringWithForbiddenChars
  FORBIDDEN_LINK_CHARS = {" " => "+", ...}
  def to_linkable
    gsub Regexp.union(FORBIDDEN_LINK_CHARS.keys), FORBIDDEN_LINK_CHARS
  end
  def to_linkable!
    self.tap do |s|
      s.gsub! Regexp.union(FORBIDDEN_LINK_CHARS.keys), FORBIDDEN_LINK_CHARS
    end
  end
end
String.prepend StringWithForbiddenChars
# or to extend the specific instance of a string:
# (str = "hello world").extend(StringWithForbiddenChars)

"hello world".to_linkable
#⇒ "hello+world"
```

Comment: thanks, will dive into the module thing of Ruby next!

Comment: The main reason I have this posted is not the module. My code has 1 `gsub` call, while all others given answers call `gsub` `N` times, where `N` is the amount of chars to be substituted.

Answer (score 1):

When you write `class String; ...; end` inside another class you are creating new class instead of editing existing ruby core `String` class. Basically it can be said like `String::ABC != String`. So you should firstly define your new String method like this:

```
class String
  FORBIDDEN_CHARS = {" " => "+", "'" => "%27", "/" => "%2F", ":" => "%3A", "&" => "%26"}

  def to_linkable
    FORBIDDEN_CHARS.each{ |key, value| self.gsub!(key,value) }
    self
  end      
end
```

After that you can use this method in any place with string objects. For example in your `SomeService` class

```
class SomeService
  def my_function(input)
    #now do something fancy with the input
    var = "#{input}    " #a String is created
    var.to_linkable
    # continue with something fancy
  end
end
```

So in the end you can do this:

```
SomeService.new.my_function("': 123123&")
# =>"%27%3A+123123%26++++"
```

Comment: @Ilya Ofc, give me a minute)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to "pollute" the whole string *class*, you can [`extend`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Object.html#method-i-extend) a specific string *instance* with a module:

```
module SomeService
  FORBIDDEN_CHARS = {" " => "+", "'" => "%27", "/" => "%2F", ":" => "%3A", "&" => "%26"}

  class ABC
    def my_function(input)
      # ...
      var = # a String is created
      var.extend(Linkable)
      var.to_linkable
      # ...
    end
  end

  module Linkable
    def to_linkable
      FORBIDDEN_CHARS.each { |key, value| gsub!(key,value) }
    end
  end
end
```